# Did I get this privilege before I had enough reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

This morning, I awoke to see that I gained the "create tag synonyms" privilege - which is usually awarded at 2.5k rep - but I only have 2499 rep, and I can't see anywhere that I would've gained the 1 rep and then lost it again.

Below is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: Achievements tab showing me earning the privilege with my reputation of 2499 also showing]

When I logged out yesterday, I believe I had 2489 rep (after answering and getting an upvote on the regex/JavaScript question).

Did I get this privilege by accident? I'm not complaining that I have it early, just wondering *how*.

Comment: Related [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73674).

Comment: Did you downvote an answer?

Comment: Well if everything is correct, right now you actually do not have the privilege.

Comment: Most likely, you got the privilege briefly, and lost it because of a reputation loss event that's not recorded in your profile. Probably an "un"-something that came shortly after the other event. Unupvote. Unaccept. Deleted post. Something like that. Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/reputation ?

Comment: @yivi my reputation page looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krvo5.png) - I don't see anything unusual. Must just be an "un"-something then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, with your reputation at 2499, you do not have the privilege.

As explained in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73674), if your reputation is once above the threshold, you will be shown the message. It's also shown only once, so if you cross 2500 again and get the privilege, you will not be shown it again.

There are events that can cause reputation changes, but aren't shown. That's explained in an [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139615) (I only quote in full what I think might be most likely the reason):

> ### My reputation dropped, but I don't see anything listed!
>
> This can be caused by one of several different reasons:
>
> - **Removed posts are hidden.** [...]
> - **Reversal events from the same day.** When you receive an upvote and a subsequent unupvote event (or an accept and an unaccept, or a downvote and an undownvote) from the same user on the same day, the events collapse into each other and are not displayed in your reputation history. This was primarily done to prevent users from spamming a user's reputation history with consistent events reversing each other. A reversed event (unupvote, undownvote, unaccept) will only appear if it occurs on a day other than the day the original event occurred.
> - **Background processes.** [...]

Comment: Weirdly though, my reputation went up yesterday by exactly 20 (from 2479 to 2499) - I've checked my [reputation page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krvo5.png) (thanks to yivi's suggestion) and I don't see anything which suggests someone removed any votes or anything got deleted. I guess someone must've voted and then retracted their vote on an answer I provided.