# Does StackOverflow use only upvoted reputation for assigning privileges?

Tags: bug

While writing the title of this question I realized it's kind of a weird question, but bear with me.

My reputation on SO is **2,498** as of posting this, and I've gotten this message:

> You've earned the "create tag synonyms" privilege!

Which is nice and all, but it's reserved for users with a reputation of **2,500 and above**.

Again, my reputation is ***2,498***. I've not been downvoted from 2,500 as I can see from my reputation tab, so 2,498 is the maximum I've ever reached.

From the obvious `2498 < 2500`, why have I gotten this privilege? Does SO not count downvotes while checking if a person has earned a privilege? If so, does that mean a person who has been severely downvoted but with 2500 upvoted rep can receive this privilege?

I've checked a bunch of times, and my rep has never crossed 2500, so there's no chance of me getting that amount only to be downvoted.

This isn't really important to the site's functioning, but I just found this out of the ordinary.

**Edit:** as u/yivi has pointed out in the comment below, I checked stackoverflow.com/reputation, and it showed me this at the end

```
-- 2020-02-15 rep +50   = 2358      
 2  60255349 (10)
 2  60255349 (10)
 2  60255349 (10)
 1  60249410 (15)
 2  60249410 (10)
 1  60255349 (15)
-- 2020-02-17 rep +70   = 2428      
 1  60274662 (15)
-- 2020-02-19 rep +15   = 2443      
 2  60389951 (10)
 2  60390467 (10)
 2  49595866 (10)
 1  60389951 (15)
 2  60389951 (10)
-- 2020-02-25 rep +55   = 2498      
-- 2020-02-26 rep 0     = 2498   
** rep today: 0
** rep this week (2020-02-23 - 2020-02-29): 55
** rep this month (2020-02-01 - 2020-02-29): 418
** rep this quarter (2020-01-01 - 2020-03-31): 418
** rep this year (2020-01-01 - 2020-12-31): 418
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 2498 :)

days represented 140
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days
earned 226 reputation from suggested edits
```

I hope posting this isn't in violation of some rule, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You reached 2500 momentarily, and you dropped below again. A deleted post was probably involved. Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/reputation ?

Comment: I just did, and the last values seen were both `2,498`.

Comment: @yivi I've posted the last few lines of the data, if you could check it out that'd be great.

Comment: If someone upvoted you, and then undid their upvote in the 5 minutes grace period, it wouldn't be reflected there I think. And for a couple of minutes you would have been over 2.5k.

Comment: @yivi That makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @ivarni You're right, it is most likely the same question, I should've searched better for it. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Premature privilege achievement notification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274306/premature-privilege-achievement-notification). Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280575/7296893, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389764/7296893. This happens quite often